# Problem connecting to SOAP API using Trustpilot

Tags: magento-enterprise, soap, soap-api-v2

I am trying to connect trustpilot product reviews to Magento for a customer.

When I open the pages where the SOAP API is connecting everything seems alright and I get the XML pages.

The error stems from the response containing an invalid body whenever an error occurs in their API. When we try to determine if we can login to Magento we first try login in with WSI mode, and if we get an error we fall back to V2 mode. We should login with V2 mode, but the error we get by trying WSI mode looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Service Error
Date: Fri, 07 Aug 2015 09:00:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=rann0j4j9fk99iljut0f7rbkt0; expires=Fri, 07-Aug-2015 11:00:51 GMT; path=/; domain=www.mydomain.com; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: NO_CACHE=1; expires=Fri, 07-Aug-2015 11:00:51 GMT; path=/; domain=www.mydomain.com; secure; httponly
Vary: User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 879
Connection: close
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Procedure 'loginParam' not present</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Class 'Mage' not found</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Class 'Mage' not found</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"
```

It contains three XML documents in the body as you can see. The Content-Type is "text/xml; charset=utf-8", which makes the body invalid.

What could be the issue that there are 3 responses instead of just one?
I´m using Magento Enterprise 1.7
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean CE 1.7?

Comment: No I mean EE 1.7.1

Comment: The first thing you should do is open a support ticket with Magento. They will help you. Your version is the CE1.3 Equivalent which was release in Jan 2010 so it is more than 5 years old now. You should consider an upgrade. You Sales tables are EAV and will perform poorly at scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to Magento Support I came to the conclusion that Magento Enterprise 1.7.1 is not supporting WS-I Compliance which is needed for this.